# How to delete topics in the Firebase Cloud Messaging console?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have looked over for ways on how to delete the option to select a topic when filling out the message composer, and have only found someone saying that a topic should be automatically deleted when no one is subscribed to it. I have unsubscribed myself (the only person in the topics) from several topics that I wanted to delete, but the option to select them still comes up in the menu. For clarity, here is a picture of what I'm talking about. [Firebase Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlZ9w.png)

I would like to delete the "12thth", "12", and "9thth" topics from ever being shown again when composing a message. I have unsubscribed myself from all of them, but they won't disappear. I don't know what to do next.

Comment: If there's not an obvious way to do this, then there is likely not a way at all.  Contact Firebase support directly with your concerns about the Firebase console.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, cannot delete a firebase topic even after unsubscribing all members of that topic